# What does そうするの mean here?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, manga

I came across this phrase in Yotsubato! manga. (ch.82, pg.35)

[image: yotubsato chapter 82, page 35, そうするの]

Source: http://raw.senmanga.com/Yotsubato!/82/35

What does `そうするの` mean here (middle panel)? As far as I can tell, the `の` is most probably an explanatory `の`. I think it means "yea just like that" or literally "to do so" but the literal meaning somehow doesn't feel right. I think it is most probably "just like that" from reading the text bubble that comes before it but I am confused here.

I tried searching `そうするの` on the web but couldn't find much that relates to above context. As a phrase what does `そうするの` mean here? I couldn't find any more examples that use `そうするの`. Any examples would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The の expresses 命令 (imperative/command). According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171157/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE/):

> の
>   2⃣［終助］活用語の連体形に付く。
>   ３ 強く決めつけて**命令**する意を表す。「余計なことを言わない**の**」「遊んでばかりいないで勉強する**の**」

And 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> の
>   ㊁〘終助〙
>   ❹ 軽く**命じる**のに使う。「さっさと着替える**の**」「強い子は泣かない**の**」
>   ◈(表現) ㊁は多く女性が使う... ④は子供など目下の相手に対して使う。

This の is a sentence-ending particle (終助詞) expressing a relatively light command. It's often used by females, normally towards someone who is inferior to or younger than the speaker.

> そう。そうするの。
>   *lit.* "Yes. Do (it) that way."

So here the girl is talking to her dad a little arrogantly (but that might be how she usually talks to him?)

Comment: Thanks! Is this command form different from other command forms like nasai or ~ro form ? Perhaps a little milder ?

Comment: @retrazil Yes, this form sounds more feminine and much milder than "~ro", and more casual and a bit milder than ~nasai.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it the same way as you said at first, but I also believe that here, the use of the particle の is used as an emphasis at the end of the statement (in a way I kind of imagine it like a です) and I think it's mostly used by girls or children who are more soft spoken. 
The translation would sound like "I will do that" or "That's what I will do". Then she says 
それでいい。。。 which would translate like "It's fine if I do that..." or "It's OK like this". Hope I got the nuances alright and I also hope that it helps!