# Why does this sentence 「授業中は、おしゃべりしないの」use しない instead of するな

Tags: grammar

So I got this sentence

> 授業中は、おしゃべりしないの

from this [article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/particle-no-nominalizer/) in Tofugu.com.

It's supposed to translate to "Don't chat during class!".

Why does it use しない instead of するな? I thought to say "don't" as a command you're supposed to use するな?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47610/9831